# What is the right way to be generic over anything that looks like a slice?

Tags: rust

I have a struct that involves some data stored in a slice.  I would like to let the user decide whether that slice is a reference or owned, stored on the stack or the heap, etc, all I care about is that it's some sort of slice somewhere.

```
pub struct A<T: WhatGoesHere?>(pub T);

A(vec![1, 2, 3]);  // Mutable on heap
A([1, 2, 3]);      // Mutable on stack
A(&[1, 2, 3]);     // Immutable
```

At first I tried the deref trait, `T: Deref<Target=[u32]>`, and for impl's that require mutability I would bound by `DerefMut`.  That works for the vec, but it doesn't like the other two.

Then I read about the `Borrow` trait, `T: Borrow<[u32]>`.  Seemed like a good fit and I could bound on `BorrowMut` for mutability.  This one likes the vec and the array, but the slice can't be borrowed as an array.  I thought maybe I should be using `Borrow<&[u32]>` but I can't figure out the lifetimes.

Finally, I tried `T: AsRef<[u32]>`.  This works for all 3!  But for mutability `AsMut` doesn't require `AsRef` (why?) so I have to bound on `AsRef<[u32]> + AsMut<[u32]>`.  That feels weird and I have to trust that those two references are to the *same slice* and the user didn't do something weird.  It doesn't quite feel like it's the *right* thing to do.

What's the right bound for `T`?  If `AsRef` is indeed the right thing should I be worried about `AsMut` referencing a different slice or am I being too paranoid?

Comment: It depends, what is your actual use case on `T` ?

Comment: What I meant is you can handle this kind of need by implementing different behaviors: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9c88d5c43af6fb6ace639b681e49f55f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question directly: `AsRef` and `AsMut` are the reasonable choice and you don't even need to bind to both for the case of `AsMut`.

However, depending on what you want to achieve with this slice, you might even want to consider using [`Read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html), [`Write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html), or their async equivalents ([`AsyncRead`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.24/futures/io/trait.AsyncRead.html), [`AsyncWrite`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.24/futures/io/trait.AsyncWrite.html)).

Comment: It appears you do need to bind both.  When I do ```impl<T: AsMut<[u32]>> A<T>``` I get ```the trait `AsRef<[u32]>` is not implemented for `T` ```

Comment: As for what I want to achieve.  One thing I need is to implement a recursive algorithm that depends on passing around references to subslices, so unfortunately I don't think I can get away with a different interface.